# How To Count Null Values With This Query

Tags: sql

I'm messing around in my school's database and I am trying to count the `null` values in this query:

```sql
SELECT Depart_ID, DepartName,
       COUNT(Name) AS employees, 
       SUM(Salary) AS 'Total salary'
FROM Ch4Employee AS E
INNER JOIN Ch4Department AS D 
   ON E.Depart_ID = D.ID
GROUP BY Depart_ID, DepartName
```

Any tips?

Comment: NULL values in which field?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count NULL salaries, do `count(*) - count(salary)`, because `count(*)` counts all rows, and `count(salary)` counts the *non-null* values.

E.g.

```
SELECT Depart_ID, DepartName,
       COUNT(Name) AS employees, 
       SUM(Salary) AS 'Total salary',
       COUNT(*) - COUNT(Salary) AS null_salaries
FROM Ch4Employee AS E
INNER JOIN Ch4Department AS D 
   ON E.Depart_ID = D.ID
GROUP BY Depart_ID, DepartName
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> select Depart_ID, DepartName, COUNT(Name) as employees, SUM(Salary) as 'Total salary' from Ch4Employee AS E 
> inner join Ch4Department as D on E.Depart_ID = D.ID
> group by Depart_ID, DepartName
> HAVING COUNT(Name) = 0
> ```

If you want to check the values ​​after aggregation you have to use Having.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Actually, how does this answer the OP's question? Where is the 40 coming from?

Comment: Syntax error. One GROUP BY too many.